# React Native iphone 5 view issue

Tags: ios, react-native, view, platform

In the below code I am facing a problem with iphone 5, the StatusBar is being covered by the SafeAreaview and if I used status bar to margin from top, that affects the iphone 6 and x which makes the margin from to larger.

```
 componentWillMount() {
        this.startHeaderHeight = 45
        this.marginTopHeader = 0
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
            this.startHeaderHeight = 30 + StatusBar.currentHeight
            this.marginTopHeader = 30 + this.marginTopHeader
        }

    }
    render() {
        var width = Dimensions.get('window').width - 128;
        var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        return (
            <SafeAreaView  style={{
                height: this.startHeaderHeight, flexDirection: 'row',
                borderBottomColor: '#ddd', backgroundColor: '#3A3658', marginTop: this.marginTopHeader
            }} >

                <Icon
                    lightTheme
                    style={{ marginLeft: 8, marginRight: 5, marginTop: 9, color: 'white' }} size={25} name="ios-menu" onPress={() => {
                        this.props.draw();
                    }}    />
            <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 7}}>

                <Icon style={{ color: '#fff',marginTop:11 ,padding:0,}} size={25} name="ios-cart" onPress={() => {
                        this.props.cart();
                    }}>
                   <Text style={{color:'red', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:10}}>{this.props.cartItemCount}</Text>

                    </Icon>

</View>
            </SafeAreaView >);}
```